# Подскажите как создать строку ввода с выбором города?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Нужно сделать поле в котором выбирается город, т.е можно поле предназначено больше для поиска города среди списка который открывается по нажатию на это поле. Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoSuggestBox. К нему привязывайте список городов. При вводе каждой буквы фильтруйте список.